# How to specify very specific range using read_xlsx() function in R

Tags: r

How can I read multiple columns from specific rows from an excel sheet using the `read_xlsx()`

Example: `B4:C242`, `F5:G341`, `J4:K256`

Comment: you could read in the whole sheet and than subselect like this for the frist example (assuming column A has been read in also): df[c(4:242), c(2:3)]

Comment: To read _one_ of these 3 ranges, you can use the `range` argument in `readxl::read_xlsx()`. You can't read these 3 ranges at once though.